# Bricked phone during root process

Tags: rooting, unbricking

So, I was in the process of rooting my phone and when it was rebooting, the PC lost connection to the USB (had a faulty driver). The phone is now completely bricked, no recovery mode, no download mode, and flashing with SP Flash Tools did nothing. Luckily it was just a cheap China phone, so no huge loss!

But if the phone was bricked before the root was completed (in the process), would it be identified as rooted? Just interested as to where in the stage the unlocked bootloader, etc. is applied.

Answer (score 0):

China phone and locked bootloader? I don't think so.

If it was a locked bootloader and if you tried to flash some other kernel, I think it's bricked (permanently). And as you said, you were in the process of rooting your phone. That means I can say you had already unlocked the bootloader.

If the phone restarted and it got disconnected, it means the issue might be related (rarely) due to the root process because you saying it's not showing up anything. It might be possible that your battery is low. Also, try some other key combinations and try to plug in your phone with some key pressed (sometimes it's the process to unbrick the phone).

Comment: I've tried all key combinations etc. Whatever the issue was the phone is now bricked and flashing to stock won't work. Not planning on doing it because it would cost too much to send back and be too much hassle but would the manufacturer even be able to tell I had tried to root?

Comment: Yes they can get to know that you have tried to root it... But as in your case you might trick them... Just day that the phone is not turning on and they will recover it with their firmware and tools.... ;-)

Comment: *"China Phone and Locked bootloader?"* -- I think you meant a Mediatek device and locked bootloader. I have OnePlus One which is a Chinese non-Mediatek phone but comes with locked bootloader. I think Yu phones which are also Chinese comes with locked bootloader.

Comment: @LokeshJain ah ok :P To be honest I doubt that for a phone that cost $140 they would be so bothered to check and at worst, surely they would just reinstall the firmware for a small fee?

Comment: @Firelord Yes I think he meant MTK Phones. Mine had an MTK 6582 Quad Core Chip

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that may work.

1. Buy or get a second cable.
2. Follow these instructions (more to buy, and it should work)
   http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/help/guide-how-to-make-usb-jig-reset-binary-t1604707
3. It should have booted into download mode. Install the stock ROM.
4. Done!

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks but it looks a bit complex for me :P

Comment: Its your only method, man. Unless you want to try getting lucky by blaming a "manufacture error", but I doubt It'll be believed